# How do you block a user on Minecraft Bedrock Realms?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms

Is there a setting in Bedrock Realms that will allow me to block a user? If so, I can't find it.

Related question: If a user gained access via a shared link to the realm, does creating a new link (which invalidates the old one) end up blocking users that aren't my friends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Realms main menu, you should have a edit button next to the Realm (the pencil icon) that shows a menu with different options. What you are looking for is Members menu, which lists all the players invited. From there, you should be able to remove the access to those players you don't want on your realm.

From that menu you should also be able to define Members' permissions for players joining from invite, and simply set them as Visitor. In this way, players that gained access via shared link cannot interact with the world or any other player. This means that every other trusted user who received your shared link needs to be upgraded, at least, as a Member.

See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gllu_ZmlkUE) for more information.

---

From different Reddits:

> Where you click share link and you copy there should be a little refresh button that changes the link. I'm pretty sure this disables the previous one.

> In the same place where it says “invite members” there’s a tab called “share link.” He needs to go to the share link tab and press the refresh button, it looks like an arrow in a loop. It will ask for confirmation to create a new link and invalidate the old one.

> you can both regenerate the code to make the old one invalid as well as setting the realm to invite only

Also from [Minecraft.net](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/article/introducing-realms-invite-links):

> If it’s getting a bit crowded, you can cancel the old invite link so no one else can use it – just refresh the link from your Realms member settings. **Only the newest version of your invite link will allow new players to join**.
> When you refresh an invite link, **anyone who has previously joined will still be in the Realm whitelist and able to join the world**, but no new players will be able to use that link to gain access.

This invalidates the old shared link. Players who gained access via old link are NOT automatically blocked, but you can always manually remove them from Members list, since they cannot join anymore.

Source [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/mcrealmsservers/comments/gca8g4/changing_the_realm_invite_code/), [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/realms/comments/i8x9o8/how_to_get_a_new_realm_linkdisable_the_old_one/) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/realms/comments/ism14l/can_you_change_realm_codes/).

Comment: Thanks, I do know those things. I am asking about if/how I can completely block a user so they are unable to join the realm/world.

Comment: @EJMak answer updated

Comment: Accepting this answer, but still wishing for clearer documentation/harder evidence for: (1) “invite only” setting. I don’t see this option. (2) Is “whitelist” absolutely synonymous with “members” list, or is there any nuance? (3) Can I be certain that any player who joined via a link [or any other means] will have had their name added to the members list?

Comment: @EJMak I'll do some research for (1). (2) whitelist is defenitely a synonym of "member list", since you can exclude unwanted players from there. For (3) you can easily try it by yourself (or even quicker, check whether you have listed uninvited players), I don't own a Realms subscription so I can't test that, but I think it's true.